# How can I find all matches of a string in a directory?

Tags: grep

Using grep (or some other utility), is it possible to find all matches of a regular expression in a folder (searching the text of each file?) I want to find every match of the regular expression `zenity` within a specific folder, so that I can find the file that contains the string `zenity`.

Comment: Alternatively, how can I find all matches of a regular expression in a directory?

Comment: Go to the directory and type grep -l <keyword> * . This will list only the file names that contain the keyword. But it doesnt search sub directories. If you need to recursively search in sub directories as well then use a combination of find and grep commands. Refer here http://wilddiary.com/find-files-containing-my-text/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using GNU grep, you can use `-r`.

```
grep -r zenity directory
```

Otherwise, if your `grep` implementation does not have any options for recursion, you can use `find` and `grep`:

```
find directory -exec grep -H zenity {} +
```

Comment: Will this search the folder recursively, and is it the same as `grep -R zenity directory`? Does capitalization matter, in this case? (It was written this way before the answer was edited.)

Comment: @AndersonGreen Yes, and yes. `-r` and `-R` are the same in GNU grep (`-r` is merely portable to other implementations).

Comment: How would the command be altered if I wanted to search for a regex instead if a string?

Comment: @AndersonGreen `zenity` *is* a regex. By default, GNU `grep` uses [BRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions).

Comment: Beware that GNU `grep -r` follows symlinks when descending directories, which is generally not what you want. Note that `grep` implementations are more likely to support `-r` than `-H`